# Computing volume of Riemannian manifolds and its $n$-sheeted covering

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, volume, covering-spaces, isometry

I have a question-

It is given that $f: M \to N$ is an $n$-sheeted covering map and a local isometry then I have to show that volume$(M) = n$ volume$(N)$, where $M$ and $N$ are Riemannian manifolds.

Let $p$ be an element in $M$, and let $(U,(x_1,...x_n))$ be a coordinate chart around $p$. Now $f(p) \in N$, let $V$ be an open set in $N$ and $(V,(y_1,...y_n))$ be a coordinate chart around $f(p)$ in $N$.

Now, looking at the expression of the volume of a region $R $ in manifold,
$$ vol(R) = \int_{R} \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} dx_{1}...dx_{n}    $$

it seems like we have to use local isometry and covering space definition at some point to express $g_{ij}$, Riemannian-metric of $M$ in terms of Riemannian-metric $h_{ij}$ of $N$....I've been trying to play around with the definitions, but unsuccessfully!

Can someone give a hint on where to proceed from here?

Comment: It might help to consider the case where $N$ is a ball and $M$ is a covering by $n$ balls with the identity map. Then the result should be easy. You can reduce the general case to this using a partition of unity on $N$ and compatible partition on $M$.

Comment: For the case where $M\to N$ is a covering of a ball by $n$ balls, the restriction to each connected component of $M$ will be a bonafide isometry so each component will have the same volume as $N$

Comment: Another suggestion for compact (orientable) manifolds: let $\omega$ be the Riemannian volume form on $N$, the Riemannian volume form on $M$ is $f^*\omega$. Then it remains to prove that $\deg f=n$, which in nicest settings can be done using the “sign formula”.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward can you please give my attempt at an answer a read? I fear there is something very wrong with it.

Comment: @Mindlack thanks for your comment but I haven't covered the discussion on n-forms yet (I'm following do Carmos's text and he mostly goes without it)

Comment: @Mindlack: and what if $N$ is non-orientable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is the following.

For each point $p\in N$, the fiber $f^{-1}(p)$ is a set of $n$ points in $M$. Each such point has a neighbourhood such that the restriction of $f$ to it is an isometry. Now take the intersection of the images of these sets, which will be some open neighbourhood $p \in U \subset N$. By its definition, the restriction of $f$ to each connected component of $f^{-1}(U)$ will be an isometry. I claim you can prove the following (let $\nu$ denote the volume form on $N$ corresponding to the metric):

**Lemma**

$$Vol(f^{-1}(U)) = \int_{f^{-1}(U)}f^*(\nu)  = n\cdot \int_{U}\nu = n\cdot Vol(U)$$

In fact, we have the following slightly stronger statement:

**Lemma** For any function $\psi$ and a volume form $\nu$,

$$\int_{f^{-1}(U)}f^*(\psi\nu)  = n\cdot \int_{U}\psi\nu $$

This lemma is a local version of the statement you want. We used the local isometry property here. We would now like to make it global. How do you typically achieve such a thing in differential geometry? One common strategy is to use a partition of unity.

Take a cover of $N$ by open sets $U_\alpha$, such that for each $U_\alpha$, the restriction of $f$ to each connected component of $f^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is an isometry. (I claim you can do this, but you should check carefully that it is true).

Take a partition of unity $\{ \psi\}$ on $N$ that is subordinate to your chosen open cover (I omit indices). The volume form for our Riemannian metric, $\nu$, is equal to

$$ \nu = \sum \psi \cdot \nu.$$

(where the sum is over functions in our partition). Now

$$ Vol(M) = \int_M f^*\nu = \int_M f^*\left(\sum \psi \cdot \nu\right) = \sum\int_M f^* \left(\psi \cdot \nu\right) = \sum\int_{f^{-1}(U_\alpha)} f^* (\psi \cdot \nu)$$

(if your volume is infinite there might be some convergence issues around commuting the sum and integral, but this case can probably be handled separately). By our lemma,

$$ \int_{f^{-1}(U_\alpha)} f^* \psi \cdot \nu = n \cdot \int_{U_\alpha} \psi \cdot \nu $$

Putting this together with the fact that $\psi$ is a partition of unity, we continue from above:

$$\sum\int_{f^{-1}(U_\alpha)} f^* (\psi \cdot \nu) = n\sum  \int_{U_\alpha} \psi \cdot \nu = n  \int_{M} \sum\psi \cdot \nu =n  \int_{M}  \nu = n Vol(N)$$

Comment: Dear friend, You said that  "Let $\nu$ denote the volume form on $N$." what if $N$ is non-orientable? there is no such volume form.

Comment: If N is non-orientable then we would never be asking questions about it's volume, would we?

Comment: Yes we would. This is Problem 16-3(b) in _Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds._

Comment: Are you sure about your (nice) solution? This is your own attempt or you've seen it somewhere?

Comment: I wrote this three years ago, I can't possibly remember. I *think* I came up with it pretty quickly on my own. After all, using partitions of unity ofor integration on manifolds is a *classic* template for a proof... Whether I am sure or not is irrelevant, you should check for yourself instead of relying on the opinion of someone else on the internet.

Comment: In any case, obviously my answer to the question assumes certain things and might not apply to whatever situation you are describing. My version of Lee doesn't have a chapter 16 so I don't know how to address your questions (nor do i have time to do so). Figure it out for yourself.

Comment: [see on google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA435&lpg=PA435)

Comment: I guess its probably an easy exercise to adapt what I wrote to densities then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to solve this question thanks to the hints by AnonymousCoward, I'm sure there are some major flaws and I'd like to have them pointed out by someone.

Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{{\alpha}\in I}$ be a locally finite covering (by co-ordinate charts) of $N$ and $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{ \alpha \in I}$ be a smooth partition of unity. Let these ${U_{\alpha}}$s be open balls (WHY?)

Now, let $x \in N$. As $f: M \mapsto N$ is a covering map, there exists an open neighborhood $U_{\alpha}$ containing $x$ such that $f^{-1}(U_{\alpha}) = \cup_{k=1}^{n}  V_{k}  $ where $V_k \cap V_l = \phi$ for $k \neq l$ and 
$V_k \subset M$ is an open ball (again why?)

Also, $ restr{f}{V_{k}} : V_{k} \mapsto U_{\alpha}$ for all $k=1,...,n$ is a homeomorphism. And as $f$ is given to be a local isometry, so $restr{f}{V_{k}}$ is an isometry, and therefore by definition if $g_{ij} $ is metric component of Riemannian-metric on $N$ and $h_{ij}$ is metric component of Riemannian-metric on $M$ then we must have $g_{ij} = h_{ij}$ for all $i,j = 1,...n$.

And so, $vol(U_{\alpha})$ which depends on metric components $g_{ij}$s is the same as $vol(V_{k})$

Now what can I do??

Comment: I posted a sketch of what might be a proof. There are several details I have not bothered to check.

Comment: Thanks. I will check out your post and work through it...but could you point out the faults in mine, if you have time. I think to avoid future mistakes, it's good to know where I'm going wrong in my reasoning..rather than copy someone else's solution/hint. But otherwise, I'll be happy with just your hint/post, so thank you!

Comment: What I put in my answer is mainly an explanation of why partitions of unity will help, and how to choose your open cover. Hopefully reading it will answer your WHY? questions.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward thanks!